# Live analysis of variable values (LUA)

Tags: debugging, variables, lua, breakpoints

In some programming IDE's like Visual Studio, it is possible to see the value of variables if you set a break point. (see picture)

[image]

Is there also a LUA IDE which has this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Most IDEs](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaIntegratedDevelopmentEnvironments) support tooltips and watch windows that show the value of a variable or an expression when the debugging is suspended, but I'm not aware of any Lua IDE that shows the values in the same way as VS does. [This is a screenshot](http://studio.zerobrane.com/images/debugging.png) that shows a tooltip with the value of variable `pay` in ZeroBrane Studio IDE.

Comment: Thank you, this IDE is working fine, but i cannot get the value of "i" in a for loop (for i=0, 100 do  ...)

Comment: Since `i` is only one character, you can mouse over it slightly to the right of the center and it should show the tooltip with the value. You can also select it and mouse over the selection. These tooltips are shown only during debugging.

Comment: Thank you Paul, it was my fault, it also works with watch expression. But good to know. I love this IDE